# Signals emitted from a QThread worker class do not arrive

Tags: qt, qt5, qthread

I have this simplified code:

```
class MyCustomObject {
};

class DeviceConnection : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit DeviceConnection(QObject* const parent = nullptr);

    signals:
        void readFinished(MyCustomObject result);

    public slots:
        void readFromDevice();
};

DeviceConnection::readFromDevice() {
    /* ... */
    emit readFinished(MyCustomObject());
}

void MainWindow::on_actionRead_triggered() {
    QThread* const thread = new QThread(this);
    DeviceConnection* const connection = new DeviceConnection();
    connection->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

    connect(connection, &DeviceConnection::readFinished, this, [=](MyCustomObject data) {
        /* This never runs. */
        connection->deleteLater();
        thread->quit();
    });

    QTimer::singleShot(0, connection, &DeviceConnection::readFromDevice);
}
```

This starts reading just fine. I can see in the debugger that I am getting to the `emit` line, and I am getting there in the thread. But I can also see in the debugger, and in the behavior of the code, that the `readFinished` lambda is never called. This is also true with slots that aren't lambdas. What's the problem?

Edit: This code runs fine when I don't use an extra thread, but of course it blocks the main thread while `readFromDevice()` runs.

Comment: Maybe you should omit the third parameter `this` from the `connect()` function call?

Comment: Please try entering a value for single shot timer. like 50. test and reply the result

Comment: I really doubt this code will compile as `emit readFinished()` is not a member function, `readFinished(QString data)` is. Howver, I think the real problem is outside this simplified code sample, try to construct a [mcve], i.e. remove the `MainWindow` part and call this function from inside `main` itself.

Comment: @vahancho, that parameter establishes that the lambda needs to be run in the same thread as the `this` object, in this case, in the main thread. Otherwise the lambda runs in the emitting thread. When I do this, the lambda does get called, but it fails later because it is running in the wrong thread.

Comment: @Mosi, I tried this but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Unfortunately I simplified the important bit away when I first asked the question, but I just edited it back in.

The problem is that `MyCustomObject` cannot be enqueued in the Qt message queue. To do that, you need to run this:

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyCustomObject>("MyCustomObject");
```

or

```
// ideally just after the definition for MyCustomObject
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyCustomObject);

// any time before you want to enqueue one of these objects
qRegisterMetaType<MyCustomObject>();
```

Answer (score 0):

your defined signal should take an argument of QString type.

Comment: While you are correct, that's just an error I introduced while simplifying the code. I fixed it in the writeup.

The code runs fine when I don't use QThread, but then it blocks the main thread.